# Trouble setting up Raspbian network bridge

Tags: iptables, raspbian, bridge, dnsmasq, dhcpcd

I'm trying to set up a raspberry pi as a network bridge between a wireless access point and a router (the reason for this being that I'd like to connect a device to the AP and use `tc` on the pi to simulate a poor network). The router is wired to the pi at `eth0` and the AP is wired to the pi at `eth1` (usb to ethernet adapter).

I'm using `dhcpcd` and `dnsmasq` to try accomplish this. However, even though I can connect a device to the AP and it is provided with an ip address (within the range specified in `dhcpcd.conf`), all pings (whether to domains or ip address) time out (I can't even ping the pi when connected to the AP).

I have enabled ipv4 forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:
`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

To the default `dhcpcd.conf` I've added:

```
# eth1 is connected to the AP
interface eth1
# This is the ip address of the Raspberry Pi
static ip_address=10.0.0.100/24
# This is the ip address of the router
static routers=10.0.0.1
```

My `dnsmasq.conf` looks like this (I'm not entirely sure the interface is correct, I've set it to be the interface connected to the AP but changing it to `eth0` doesn't seem to make any difference):

```
interface=eth1
listen-address=10.0.0.100
bind-interfaces
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
domain-needed
bogus-priv
dhcp-range=10.0.0.110,10.0.0.130,4h
```

I ran these commands to add iptable rules (I then saved iptables to a file and am restoring them on boot via `rc.local`):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

From what I've read, the rules above should be correctly forwarding traffic through the pi, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I checked the status of the `dhcpcd` and `dnsmasq` services but didn't see anything that looks like an error.

`dhcpcd` status:

```
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
           └─wait.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-02-26 12:02:43 GMT; 29min ago
 Main PID: 368 (dhcpcd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           └─368 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -w

Feb 26 12:02:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: eth0: offered 10.0.0.140 from 10.0.0.1
Feb 26 12:02:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: eth0: probing address 10.0.0.140/24
Feb 26 12:02:47 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: eth0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.202.179
Feb 26 12:02:47 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: eth0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
Feb 26 12:02:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: eth0: leased 10.0.0.140 for 86400 seconds
Feb 26 12:02:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: eth0: adding route to 10.0.0.0/24
Feb 26 12:02:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: eth0: adding default route via 10.0.0.1
Feb 26 12:02:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: eth0: deleting route to 169.254.0.0/16
Feb 26 12:02:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
Feb 26 12:02:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: eth1: no IPv6 Routers available
```

`dnsmasq` status:

```
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-02-26 12:02:43 GMT; 33min ago
 Main PID: 401 (dnsmasq)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dnsmasq.service
           └─401 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -r /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old,.dpkg-new --local-service --trust-anchor=.,19036,8,2,49aac11d7b6f6446702e54a1607371607a1a41855200fd2ce1cdde32f24e8fb5 --trust-anchor=.,20326,8,2,e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d0

Feb 26 12:02:50 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[401]: DHCPDISCOVER(eth1) a0:f3:c1:6d:2f:1b
Feb 26 12:02:50 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[401]: DHCPOFFER(eth1) 10.0.0.129 a0:f3:c1:6d:2f:1b
Feb 26 12:02:50 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[401]: DHCPDISCOVER(eth1) a0:f3:c1:6d:2f:1b
Feb 26 12:02:50 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[401]: DHCPOFFER(eth1) 10.0.0.129 a0:f3:c1:6d:2f:1b
Feb 26 12:02:58 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[401]: DHCPDISCOVER(eth1) a0:f3:c1:6d:2f:1b
Feb 26 12:02:58 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[401]: DHCPOFFER(eth1) 10.0.0.129 a0:f3:c1:6d:2f:1b
Feb 26 12:02:58 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[401]: DHCPREQUEST(eth1) 10.0.0.129 a0:f3:c1:6d:2f:1b
Feb 26 12:02:58 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[401]: DHCPACK(eth1) 10.0.0.129 a0:f3:c1:6d:2f:1b TL-WR702N
Feb 26 12:35:05 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[401]: DHCPREQUEST(eth1) 10.0.0.124 f4:5c:89:8e:aa:a1
Feb 26 12:35:05 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[401]: DHCPACK(eth1) 10.0.0.124 f4:5c:89:8e:aa:a1 george
```

In this status, `TL-WR702N` is the AP and `george` is a device connected to the AP.

I'm stumped as to where I went wrong. 
I was following [a tutorial](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-bridge/) for setting up a pi as bridge and have tried to debug this issue by referring to the man pages for `dnsmasq`, `dhcpcd` and `iptables` to no avail.

The pi *has* been rebooted since setting this up.

Comment: Be careful with the vocabulary: the question and tags say "bridge" (please hover on the tag's description), but the description says "routing" and has not a single bridge reference. This is not the same. The tutorial uses the word "bridge" but doesn't describe a bridge. A comment notices it: "Also, important to note that this setup is a wifi client NAT router, not technically a bridge". Can you clarify your goal? Can't you just plug the AP to the router without the RPi if your really want a bridge (the AP is already a bridge between wireless and ethernet) ?

Comment: My goal is indeed to use the Pi as a bridge, and to use the kernel's traffic control to make the network unreliable for devices connected to the AP (but not for devices connected directly to the router). I hadn't noticed the comment about it being a NAT router and not a bridge; I'll do some more research. I may have to go about this a completely different way...

Comment: try this: https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections . Don't look for a RPi tutorial, because it will surely assume the RPi is the AP (which it is not). Also note the wiki is a bit outdated and that brctl as well as ifconfig are obsolete commands, and should be replaced with `ip link` + `ip address` (and less frequently also with `bridge ...` ), but anyway it's hidden in the /etc/network/ config

Comment: You were absolutely right. Following the debian wiki was much more straightforward and actually worked like a charm, no fiddling about with iptables or dnsmasq. Thank you. If you want to write that in an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Just realized I didn't write the answer. It's done. Also added some more information (especially a link to a netem question similar to your own goal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the linked tutorial ( https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-bridge/ ), I could conclude that this *is not* a bridge tutorial, but a NAT/router tutorial. Even a comment in it also states:

> Also, important to note that this setup is a wifi client NAT router,
>   not technically a bridge.

So to actually use a bridge, follow a bridge tutorial. Since it's Raspbian, Debian's [BridgeNetworkConnections](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections) should be good enough. The bridge-utils package mentionned isn't really needed for its (obsolete) [`brctl`](https://manpages.debian.org/brctl.8) command which could be completely replaced with modern [iproute2](https://packages.debian.org/stable/iproute2)'s [`ip link`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-link.8) and (if actually needed) [`bridge`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/bridge), but for its [`bridge-utils-interfaces`](https://manpages.debian.org/bridge-utils/bridge-utils-interfaces.5) plugin for [ifupdown](https://packages.debian.org/stable/ifupdown)'s [configuration](https://manpages.debian.org/ifupdown/interfaces.5).

So in the end the configuration can be done with something similar to:

```
iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

Don't put any IP on the real interfaces, because they now become bridge ports and their layer 3 settings will be ignored. Also not vital but the bridge should inherit its first's interface MAC address. So if it really matters and you'd rather have eth1's MAC used, put it first in the `bridge_ports` command (this would probably also change the router's DHCP offer).

Now change any reference to `eth0` in various settings that would state an interface into `br0` instead, but chances are you don't even need this, since for example you don't need anymore `dnsmasq`. That's it.

Some extra informations:

- If you ever use `iptables` instead or in addition of `ebtables` to try to do filtering between the two interfaces (hint: you should probably not, it's a bridge now, not a router, but it's needed for a stateful transparent firewalling bridge), please be aware, if activating [br-netfilter](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) of the special interactions between the bridge filtering and the IP filtering layers: [ebtables/iptables interaction on a Linux-based bridge](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html). This can lead to hard-to-debug results when not knowing about it.
- Many [`tc qdisc`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc.8#QDISCS) effects (like [`netem`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-netem.8)) work on the outgoing direction (egress) only. Since you're between both interfaces `eth0` and `eth1` , you could ponder that you can always find an egress interface for a specific intended action, but if it's done on `eth0` then the RPi itself can be affected on the internet side, which is probably not what is wished. You can avoid this by attaching an [Intermediate Functional Block device](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/ifb#ifb_example) (`ifb0`) to `eth1`: this artificially inserts an interface between the ingress and the rest of the network code. This interface is thus now an egress interface from the point of view of `eth1`'s incoming data flow, and can happily accept egress features like `netem`. For any other interpretation it's part of the ingress flow. You can now then apply TC to `eth1` and `ifb0` and leave `eth0` undisturbed. More informations in my answer there: [Simulation of packet loss on bridged interface using netem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421462/simulation-of-packet-loss-on-bridged-interface-using-netem/463728#463728)